# I have a problem converting a Unicode character into two hexadecimal bytes in UTF-8

Tags: unicode, utf-8

I have a problem and I hope you can help me... basically I just started UTF-8 and Unicode, the professor wrote a text file, he wrote "ciaò" inside and showed us the content, displaying each character in hexadecimal (for example the 'c' is 0063, the 'i' is 0069, the 'a' is 0061). The problem is the 'ò' character, which is formed by 2 bytes in UTF-8: c3; b2 (hex). The exercise he gave us is to verify that in UTF-8 the 'ò' character is written just like that (for the resolution he advised us to look at the Unicode website).

I tried to do the exercise this way: I saw that the character 'ò' in hex is 00F2, I transformed it into binary (11110010) and I formed the two bytes of UTF-8 filling the bytes to complete them. |110|11110| e |10|010000|. The problem is that this way I get the following values: DE (instead of c3 for the first byte); 90 (instead of b2 for the second byte). Can someone explain me where I am wrong please?

Comment: Have you tried printing your teachers values as binary to see the difference?

Comment: Actually I tried and I saw that they were not the same (of course).

Comment: So where and what are the differences? Are the `110` and `10` start bits of the bytes the same? If so, how do the value bits differ?

Comment: Ohhhhhhh I got it now... it's the 3 zeros that I have to put at the start and not at the end! So the total number of bits in two bytes are 16: 5 are used (110 and 10) and 'ò' has 8 bits (so other 8 bits used), that means that we still have 3 bits to fill with zeros. If I put them at the end I think the number gest bigger (so it's an error) whilst if I put them at the start it doesn't. Am I correct with this explanation?

Answer (score 0):

For the character "ò", its UTF-16 representation is 00F2, and its UTF-8 representation is C3B2. I don't think you can use 00F2 to represent it in UTF-8.
To verify C3B2 is "ò", you can check a website [like this one](https://codepoints.net/U+00F2), or if you are using a linux-like terminal you can write:

```
echo -e "\xC3\xB2"
```

Which should simply print "ò".

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I figured it out:  it's the 3 zeros that I have to put at the start and not at the end! So the total number of bits in two bytes are 16: 5 are used (110 and 10) and 'ò' has 8 bits (so other 8 bits used), that means that we still have 3 bits to fill with zeros. If I put them at the end I think the number gest bigger (so it's an error) whilst if I put them at the start it doesn't.

Comment: Btw I didn't have to verify it with a website (as I couldn't understand exactly why it worked in that case) but I had to "prove it" with the binary conversion. Thanks anyways!